# calculated Correlation matrix as input to corrplot

Tags: matrix, correlation, r-corrplot

I have a table with already calculated coefficients and I would like to use corrplot to visualise it. this is the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJZcu.png)
image
and the structure of it is:

image
but it prompts the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ohm.png)
image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAWh4.png)
how can i format it to run it with corrplot?

Corrplot uses the output of

```
cor(data) a
```

s input,

Thank heaps in advance

cheers

I tried:

```
as.data.frame(datac) datac being the correlation matrix imported from csv.

as.matrix(datac)

lapply(datac, is.finite)
data3 <- read.csv("primary_vs_PDX.csv", header = T, colClasses = "numeric" )
data3 <- read.csv("primary_vs_PDX.csv", as.is = T)
```

I tried with mock values:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HQdp.png)

and it worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nUSI.png)

the problem is the structure of input files datac 9my file) vs df (mock).

I used datac on ggcorrplot and it worked, but would like to use corrplot

cheers,

carlos